# All commands disappear after get-apt --fix-broken install in Fedora17

Tags: fedora, apt

The first action I did is to upgrade my svn by

```
apt-get upgrade subversion
```

and then this showed in command line

```
apt-get unmet dependencies but it is not going to be installed
```

and suggested me to do

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
```

After doing this, I found that not only svn was upgrade but all commands was removed! I even cannot invoke `ls`.

What actions can I do to save this situation?

Comment: Are you really using `apt-get` in Fedora? And in Fedora 17 which is 9 years old?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Good catch. I almost missed the second part.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be uncharacteristically unkind here, but there are *so* many things wrong with your question it's hard to decide where to start.

First, Fedora 17 is, as per [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/releases/eol/) site, *more than nine years pasts its end-of-life*. It's unlikely you'll find any support for it, or even any manageable upgrade paths to supported versions because by now too many links in the chain will have EOLed out long ago as well.

Second, Fedora does not and never has used `apt`. It's a distribution of the Red Hat genus which uses `.rpm` packages and `yum` -- now superseded by `dnf` if I'm reading this correctly -- to manage and install packages.

`apt` is the package management system of the Debian genus of distributions,  and primarily works with `.deb` packages. I'm not sure why you installed apt on that system to begin with, and I'm somewhat impressed - in a horrified way - that it actually worked *at all*, but what I suspect happened is that in order to satisfy those 'unmet dependencies' it basically attempted to install the entire base system of whatever distribution the repository you pointed it at in `/etc/apt/sources.list` represents.

Your system is, at this point, almost certainly *hosed beyond recognition or recovery* and the only advice I can give you is to use a live USB image to move any personal data somewhere safe, then wipe and reinstall from scratch with an up-to-date version of the distribution of your choice.